# Python - language-check 1.0

Tags: python

Can anyone please let me know why my code is not providing the correct output.

My code:

```
import language_check
tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')
text='this are bad'
matches = tool.check(text)
t=len(matches)
for i in range(0,t):
    print(matches[i].ruleId,matches[i].replacements)
new=language_check.correct(text, matches)
print(new)
```

The expected answer is "These are bad" but the actual output I am getting is "This are bad"

The language_check tool detects the errors as:

> "UPPERCASE_SENTENCE_START ['This']"
>
> "THIS_NNS ['these']"

But it fails to correct the second error.
[image]

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the tool you're using, but it looks to me like the two replacements are simply incompatible: the first wants to change `this` to `This`, the second wants to change `this` to `these`.  Well, after the first replacement, there is no longer a `this` to replace!  You may need to iteratively apply replacements and then call `.check()` again, until no further replacements are found.

Comment: The tool corrects any given sentence/word in terms of spell as well as grammar.  As first letter of first word in every sentence starts with capital letter, the tool is replacing "this" to "This" than it checks for grammatical errors and find out a replacement for This which is These.

Comment: but i guess the reason for it to not replace "this" to "these" might be what you have mentioned @jasonharper

Answer (score 0):

Could you be using an old version of LanguageTool? I have installed language_check with Python 3.6.1 just to test your code and it gave me the output "these are bad".

Edit: Precisely, that's what I get on output with exact same code:

```
THIS_NNS ['these']
these are bad
```

Comment: i am using python 3.6.1 and latest version of language tool. And please do use text='this are bad'

Comment: I wonder why your output do not contain: "UPPERCASE_SENTENCE_START ['This']"

Comment: I installed everything via pip, if it helps.

Comment: I too have installed it using pip.

Comment: please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments the problem is that when the tool changes "this" to "This", there is no more "this" that can be replaced to "these". The best way to correct the sentences is to apply the correct function iteratively until no more changes can be found. To prevent infinite loop (which is impossible I guess) I added a threshold on changes.

```
import language_check

def correct(text, threshold=1000):
    tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')
    i = 0
    matches = tool.check(text)
    while matches or i < threshold:
        matches = tool.check(text)
        text = language_check.correct(text, matches)
        i += 1

    return text
```

So you can call it:

```
output = correct("this are bad.")
print(output)
```

gives you:

```
These are bad.
```

Comment: Thank You for the solution but looping over for larger sentence won't be a better option I guess.

Comment: I think there is no better way to do this because every time you loop over to find matches and correct them you end up with a bunch of other matches or just finishes. Anyway if your problem is the threshold you can set it adaptively for larger sentenecs.